# How to create xmpp stanza for gcm ccs request in sleekxmpp python?

Tags: android, python, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am using sleekmpp python to communicate with my android clients using GCM / CCS. The main problem is that the data is in json format and need to be within gcm tag. How can I achieve it ?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
import getpass
from optparse import OptionParser
import sleekxmpp
import json

from sleekxmpp import Iq
from sleekxmpp.xmlstream import ElementBase, register_stanza_plugin
REGISTRATION_ID = "APA91bF61NHoXfH4gHojuejpodfghdfvbnazqsrfsgdvfdodxdufcokojnogfvr4ijUbsTWzc-u9lsE2XkkNyQ"

class AA(ElementBase):
    name = 'gcm'
    namespace = 'google:mobile:data'
    plugin_attrib = 'aa'
    interfaces = set(['to', 'message_id', 'data'])
    sub_interfaces = interfaces

register_stanza_plugin(Iq, AA)
SERVER = 'gcm.googleapis.com'
PORT = 5235
USERNAME = "1013691256357"
PASSWORD = "AIAASDFSefeffefEFEFFeFfefefefEFEFfefefefFEffeFf7qeO1zB0Vt4"

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
else:
    raw_input = input

class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)
        self.add_event_handler("message", self.start)
    def start(self, event):
        print event
        self.send_presence()
        self.get_roster()
        self.disconnect(wait=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup logging.
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,                        format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    xmpp = SendMsgBot(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0030') # Service Discovery
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0199') # XMPP Ping

    if xmpp.connect(('gcm.googleapis.com', 5235), use_ssl=True):
      # while True:
      xmpp.process(block=True)
      to_send = {'to': REGISTRATION_ID,
                 'message_id': 'reg_id',
                 'data': {'ma_message': 'message for android',
                          'ma_title': "Reg title"}}
      xmpp.sendMessage("google", "<message><gcm xmlns='google:mobile:data'>"+json.dumps(to_send)+"</gcm></message>")

      print("Done")
    else:
        print("Unable to connect.")
```

Required xmpp stanza is this.

```
<message id="">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
  {
      "to":"REGISTRATION_ID",  // "to" replaces "registration_ids"
      "message_id":"m-1366082849205" // new required field
      "data":
      {
          "hello":"world",
      }
      "time_to_live":"600",
      "delay_while_idle": true/false,
      "delivery_receipt_requested": true/false
  }
  </gcm>
</message>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I think is because of the body tag.

Comment: Nope, I used other package of xmpp in ubuntu. `sudo apt-get install python-xmpp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`send_raw`](http://sleekxmpp.com/api/xmlstream/xmlstream.html#sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream.XMLStream.send_raw) instead, and send the full GCM message stanza in the `data` field. When I do this, I no longer see a 400 error and I instead I receive a "BAD_REGISTRATION" which is correct.